# Is there a risk to XSS attacks when assigning the input element value?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

Will assigning a value to an `input` element that was created with vanilla js cause XSS vulnerabilities?

For example

```
var inn = document.createElement('input');
//append to parent or body...

var data = request.post(someData) //make some kind of https request with a response.

in.value = data;
```

Comment: Well with so little code it's hard to tell, is that data coming from user input ?

Comment: Side note: You can't have a variable named `in`. `in` is a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No *(caveat¹)*. The value you assign to the `value` property of an `input` element is solely treated as plain text. Nothing about it is executed.

---

¹ Caveat: **If** `data` is an object with a custom `toString` function, then assigning `data` to `in.value` will implicitly call that `toString` function, which executes code. You seem to be showing `data` as the result of doing a POST, though, so I'm going to assume it can't be an object with a custom `toString` function.

Comment: yes, in the actual code, I am making a https request to the backend and then response returned is assingned like above.